# Check if server is accessible via IPv6?

Tags: c#, ipv6

Is is possible to check if a server is accessible via IPv6 with c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traverse the address list returned from [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) and check if any of the `IsIPv6xxxx` properties is set to true

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean - if you know (or can resolve) the server's hostname or DNS name to an IPv6 address, it should be possible for you to do a couple of things.

You could either send a test packet using IPv6 to the server and see if you get a response back. Alternatively, if you're going IPv6 all the way, you could change your own network layer to be IPv6 only. On newer releases of Windows server I believe you can switch IPv6 on and IPv4 off.

Hope that helps!